# Prototyping does not work with local Turnkey

Tags: mdriven

Please see the model in attachment.
I started prototyping with it. It does work with XML-Persistance, SQL and MDriven-Server, but not with local Turnkey.

Repro: Start Prototyping -> Seekers -> Action Person Seeker ->  add some new Persons with New Person -> Select one -> Show Person -> try to set Father or Mother with "Set" Button. Nothing happens. In other kinds of Prototyping the Seeker is called, and you can select a person and set it as Father or Mother.

See also Screenshot
[image]

Efim

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that your actions that will be triggered by the buttons was opted out:
[image]

You could discover this reason by checking browser console:

```
console.warn("A button action that tried to bring up a modal window did not find the backing action: " + navigate.ActionName);
```

Comment: It helped, thanks. But it is something strange that it worked in WECPOF-Prototyper with opted out

Comment: We aim to have the same end result for different technologies - but differences in interpretation of the specification may lead to findings like this. In turnkey out-opted actions are not even sent to the client and thus cannot be referenced. But will file a report on this